# How to do server-side sorting/filtering in angular-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-grid

There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/ceolter/angular-grid/issues/84) to add server-side sorting/filtering to the angular-grid project.  Has anyone found a work-around to implement this functionality with the current grid implementation?  Hacky or not, I'll still take it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have more information here:

http://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-virtual-paging/

> Any column can be sorted by clicking the header. When this happens,
>   the datasource is called again with the new sort options.
>
> The columns Age, Country and Year can be filtered. When this happens,
>   the datasource is called again with the new filtering options.

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableServerSideSorting: true,
        enableServerSideFilter: true
  }
  ...
  $scope.gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
```

The datasource has a getRows() which can use params.startRow and params.endRow, plus params.sortModel, params.filterModel to request the data from the server via an http call.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/
Rowmodeltype has to be set as infinite and instead of setRowData ,dataSource pramater has to be set.

```
rowModelType : "infinite",
enableServerSideSorting: true,
enableServerSideFilter: true
```

Built in filters like agSetColumnFilter,agTextColumnFilter,agNumberColumnFilter are only working in ag grid 15.0.0 and 16.0.0 versions, not working in 14.2.0 version.

This is plunkr for it:
https://embed.plnkr.co/S2yZkGKF7utD1KEt1pbh/